# SQL server : Db start up Validation and check the counts on few table

Tags: sql-server-2008

Creating a validation script that can be run against the archive server that confirms that databases are up and online after the refresh(SAN level) is done. The script should be small, quick but checks enough to provide good information.

Example

1. Is db online
2. Does a count of rows for a table inserted into a temp table match the count returned by a select count
3. Is the processdate value in the current processdate equal to today – 1

Comment: What is your question exactly? You've listed some requirements, but you haven't said what your problem is.